# Pasting data from clipboard into Datagrid is extremely slow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, paste

I'm implementing a custom control based on the WPF DataGrid.
One of the things I implemented is pasting from clipboard.

For some reason the approach I'm taking is performing really slow.
I did some performance evaluation and it seems that BeginEdit() is taking around 80% of exclusive samples.

Can anyone provide any insights on what I maybe doing wrong or have a different approach to pasting data into WPF DatagGrid?

Here's my method doing the work:

```
private void OnExecutedPaste(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get clipboard content
    List<object[]> rowData = ClipboardHelper.ParseClipboardDataToTypes();

    var selectedCellContent = SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(SelectedCells[0].Item);
    if (selectedCellContent != null)
    {
        var firstCell = SelectedCells.Count > 0 ? selectedCellContent.Parent as DataGridCell : null;
        // Get the start & end rows/columns indexes
        int minRowIndex = firstCell != null ? firstCell.GetParentRow().GetIndex() : Items.Count - 1;
        int maxRowIndex = minRowIndex + rowData.Count;
        int minColumnDisplayIndex = (SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow) && firstCell != null
                                        ? firstCell.Column.DisplayIndex
                                        : 0;
        int maxColumnDisplayIndex = Columns.Count - 1;
        // Go through rows
        int rowDataIndex = 0;
        for (int i = minRowIndex; i <= maxRowIndex && rowDataIndex < rowData.Count; i++, rowDataIndex++)
        {
            int columnDataIndex = 0;
            // Get row view model bound to the row
            var rowVM = Items[i];
            // Go through columns
            for (int j = minColumnDisplayIndex;
                j <= maxColumnDisplayIndex && columnDataIndex < rowData[rowDataIndex].Length;
                j++, columnDataIndex++)
            {
                // Get the column
                var column = ColumnFromDisplayIndex(j);
                // Get the value to be pasted at the cell
                object value = rowData[rowDataIndex][columnDataIndex];

                CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(rowVM, column);
                BeginEdit();
                // If first cell in the row we need to refresh item in case is the newitemplaceholder 
                // BeginEdit() may have triggered NewItemInitializer
                if (j == minColumnDisplayIndex) rowVM = Items[i];
                // Paste the value in the cell
                column.OnPastingCellClipboardContent(rowVM, value);
                //CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Cell, true);
            }
            if (!CommitEdit())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Cannot paste clipboard content at row {0}. Make sure the data is valid.", i), "Can't paste row",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                return;
            }
            if (i >= Items.Count - 1)
            {
                if (NewItemInitializer == null)
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot add new rows for additional items.", "Can't paste row",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                else
                    OnInitializingNewItem(new InitializingNewItemEventArgs(NewItemInitializer.Invoke()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have paste data on `DataGrid` ?? Move clipboard data to the binded view model, and binding will take care of showing it on UI.

Comment: @Tigran The reason I have to do this is because I'm developing a reusable control and I don't know/don't want to know what is bound to it

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?